# Derivation of gradient-bandit algorithm, Why is the sum of the derivatives is zero?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, derivative, gradient

https://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~dprecup/courses/RL/Lectures/2-bandits-2019.pdf
In above pdf document, page 19, they explain by formula:
$$\sum _{ b }^{  }{ \frac { \nabla { \Pi  }_{ t }(b) }{ \nabla { H }_{ t }(a) } } =\quad 0$$

As the title why it is equal to 0?

Answer (score 3):

It is equal to zero because $\pi$ is a probability distribution over action space. Total probability over action space has to be $1$. If you increase probability for a single action $b$, then probability has to decrease for a set of some other actions, otherwise their total sum would be larger than $1$. The total gradient for all actions has to be zero because if it wasn't zero you would increase/decrease some probabilities and you would not compensate that by decreasing/increasing some other probabilities so their total sum would not be $1$ anymore (it would be larger or lower than $1$ depending if we increased or decreased some probabilities).